# How to get the full computer name using Test Complete

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, testcomplete

How to get the full computer name using Test Complete

For example,

```
Computer Name : RAMAKRISHNA
Full Computer Name  : RAMAKRISHNA.XYZ.COM
Domain Name : XYZ.COM
```

Using TestComplete, I have tried the following:

```
log.Message sys.HostName    'Gives "RAMAKRISHNA"
log.Message sys.DomainName  'Gives "XYZ"
```

Here, I am missing to get ".COM" using TestComplete

Please help me to get the full computer like RAMAKRISHNA.XYZ.COM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using WMI.

```
Sub Test
  Log.Message getFullPCName  
End Sub 

Function getFullPCName
  Set cSystem = WMI.Service.InstancesOf("Win32_ComputerSystem").ItemIndex(0)
  getFullPCName = cSystem.Name & "." & cSystem.Domain
End Function
```

[Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) technology provides ways to manage Windows settings and operations. You can use the [Win32_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class to get information on the system. TestComplete provides an easy way to work with WMI using the corresponding object. Find more information in the [WMI Object](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/80905/) help topic.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, This served my purpose. Can you please explain the code functionality or provide any article links that helps me to get the code

Comment: I have updated my response with some details. If my answer resolves your question, I would appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry :)

Comment: @rama-krishna, I am glad that I was able to help! Could you please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the check icon to the left of the answer text? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )
WScript.Echo "Computer Name: " & strComputerName & "." & GetDomainName

Function GetDomainName()
  Dim Info 
  Set Info = CreateObject("AdSystemInfo") 
  GetDomainName = Info.DomainDNSName
End Function
```